# Using backspace with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I have a simple ncurses program set up that reads characters one at a time with getch() and copies them into a buffer. The issue I am having is detecting a press of the backspace key. Here is the relevant code:

```
while((buffer[i] = c = getch()) != EOF) {
    ++i;
    if (c == '\n') {
        break;
    }
    else if (c == KEY_BACKSPACE || c == KEY_DC || c == 127) {
        i--;
        delch();
        buffer[i] = 0;
    }
    refresh();
}
```

But when attempting to run this code, this is what appears on the screen after trying to delete characters from the line "this is a test":

```
this is a test^?^?^?
```

and the contents of `buffer` are:

```
this is a test
```

With gdb I know that the if statement checking for a delete/backspace is being called, so what else should I be doing so that I can delete characters?

Comment: Is `this is a test^?^?^?` the content of `buffer`, or is it what appears on the screen? Either way, what's the other?

Comment: `this is a test^?^?^?` is what appears on the terminal, buffer contains `this is a test`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `^?` is what's echoed to the screen when you enter a DEL character.

You could probably call `delch()` twice, but then you'd have to figure out which characters echo as two-character (or more) sequences.

Your best bet is probably to call `noecho()` and explicitly print the characters yourself.

Comment: That worked perfectly, it actually made my code a little cleaner as well. Additionally, I had to decrement `i` by 2, since I'm incrementing it before checking for a backspace. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a simpler way of doing it by using the forms library alongside ncurses. If you change your code to this:

```
#include <form.h>
while((buffer[i] = c = getch()) != EOF) {
    ++i;
    if (c == '\n') {
        break;
    }
    else if (c == KEY_BACKSPACE || c == KEY_DC || c == 127) {
        form_driver(Form, REQ_DEL_PREV);
    }
    refresh();
}
```

It will backspace without a problem. You can find some (Albeit limited) documentation for the REQ_DEL_PREV command [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/forms.html).

Comment: What is this? You've omitted every single piece of real logic out of this code. You cannot just omit the majority of the code if you're using it to answer a question...

Comment: @kevr Could you please elaborate on that? This is the code that the OP posted, modified such that backspace now works by using REQ_DEL_PREV instead of modifying the buffer directly. This is, in fact, the complete code the OP posted. I did not omit "the majority of the code" or any of it, in fact.