# ncurses and getch - Handling erase and arrow characters

Tags: c, linux, input, screen, ncurses

In a C program under Linux and `ncurses`, I need to acquire characters from the keyboard (so, from the user) and to store them into a string, which is considered complete only when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. At the same time, however, I need to display a screen echo for the user, so that he can see what he is writing and he can correct some typos, if necessary.

My bunch of code is working, but it can't handle the erase and arrow characters.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387572/using-backspace-with-ncurses) question a solution is provided to correctly **store** the string, when <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> are pressed. But what solution could be choosen in order to **display** a correct screen echo, even considering the arrow keys?

My code is essentially:

```
while(1)
{
if (getch() =! ERR)
// store the character into an array
if (getch() == 10)
// terminate the string and print it on screen
}
```

The characters are acquired through a `getch()` one by one. Like in the linked question, if I don't use `noecho()` and I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the sequence `^?` is displayed instead of removing the previous character from the screen. If I use `noecho()`, the program should show real-time to the user what's happening. Should I re-print the string at every `while` cycle? It would be cumbersome.

So, how can I correctly **display** to the user what's happening?

Comment: using [THESE](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_delch.3.asp) functions?

Comment: @LPs Yes, I can, but I would like to handle also the arrows and the *del* key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP's program used the [`keypad()`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) function, then left-cursor (arrow) and the erase key would have the same effect.  [`getnstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html) does not support inline editing (moving the cursor within the line).  (Incidentally, other implementations of curses do nothing with cursor-keys).

As an example of a program which does support inline-editing, [`dialog`](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) is useful (it works with UTF-8).  On the other hand, because it stores the responses as a plain character string, it is more complicated, say, than something explicitly written to use [`wget_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html).

[cdk](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/cdk.html#future) does not handle UTF-8.

ncurses does not provide a more interesting function because:

- that functionality is already in the [`form`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form.3x.html) library
- it does not qualify as an [*extension*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#backlog) because one can readily develop various functions of this sort without knowing the library's internals.

Recently there was a related question (for blocking I/O) in *[ncurses, print and contemporary acquire strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399323/ncurses-print-and-contemporary-acquire-strings/32408339#32408339)* (again, `dialog` does *that*).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read characters until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you probably want to use the [`getnstr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/curs_getstr.3x.html) function instead of reading a character at a time. `getnstr` will interpret erase and kill characters, although it is far from a complete line-editing system.

Otherwise, you are going to end up having to handle all the cursor movement characters yourself. That's obviously more flexible but it's also a lot more work. If you go down that route, I suggest turning echo off and manually echoing (non-control) characters because that will give you much better control over the cursor position.

Comment: Following your advice, I tried with `getnstr` and it would work. But it can handle just the *backspace* key, neither the arrows, nor the *del* key. Moreover, if I use `getnstr` the cycle blocks until the user has completed his string. As far as you know, is there a more "smart" function which can handle such keys, or some example code which performs these operations, or am I actually "forced" to handle all the possible cursor movements?

Comment: @bowpark: i don't know of a ncurses function which is more sophisticated. Outside of ncurses, there is Gnu readline, but that is not really compatible with ncurses. There are probably libraries but I'm not familiar with them, sorry.

Comment: @bowpatk: maybe look at http://invisible-island.net/cdk/manpage/cdk.3.html But if you don't want input to block and you can't move the ncurses code into a separate thread, things will be more complicated. See http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_threads.3x.html

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution, it's pretty easy and don't need noecho();

```
getyx( stdscr, y, x ); //get current cursor position
x-= 3; //go three position back, one for the char to erase, the other two to erase the backspace char ^? 
mvprintw( y, x, "   " ); //erase chars
move( y, x ); //get in right position for new input
```